# Redirecting one url to https and all other urls to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect one url to https and all other urls to http
ex: If I want to access login page of example.com, it should redirect to https://example.com/login
and if I want to access any pages other than login, they should be redirected to http://example.com/any-other-page.
Current .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule !^(login) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

This is working fine. All urls other than login are redirecting to http.
But if I add the following code to redirect login page, it is redirected to index.php

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (login) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

What I want is only login page should be redirected to https. But this is not happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the following rule in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(login)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(login)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The first set of rules check is HTTPs is off for the directory `/login/` if it is off, then it will force it to HTTPs.

The second set of rules check if HTTPs is on, if it is on then it will turn it off for everything excluding the `/login/` directory.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** you test this.

NOTE:

I'm not sure why you don't want everything to be HTTPs?... It would make for a much more secure website and would allow you to use HSTS.